# Add fixed width border around image of varying width

Tags: css

I have a number of images of items on a white background.. Some images are wider than others. I would like to add a border around the images, but want the border to be fixed width (say 100px)

Basically I want to have a variable amount of padding (between image and border) so that image width + padding (left and right) = 100px

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
    <td style = "vertical-align: middle; border-left:">
      <div style="border: 1px solid #DDDDDD; width:200px; text-align:center">
        <a href="/styles/15"><img alt="blah" class="thumbnail" src="blah" style="vertical-align: middle; border:none; height:65x; text-align:center" /></a>
       </div>
    </td>
```

Comment: you want a `border` of `100px;`?

Comment: yes, so vacant space on either side of the image, until the border

Comment: Please edit your answer so it makes sense, use images of what you wanna achieve people might have better ways than your way, pictures makes it easy to solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Please avoid inline style**

see the **[demo](http://jsbin.com/ovijaq/1/)**

**Use CSS as :**

```
.imageBox {border: 1px solid #DDDDDD; width:200px; text-align:center}
.image {vertical-align: middle; border:none; height:65x; text-align:center}
```

**and HTML as :**

```
<td class="imageBox">
    <div >
        <a href="/styles/15"><img alt="blah" class="thumbnail" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/17/MetroLigeroMad_logo_1.png"  /></a>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a Champion answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<div class="imageholder">
   <img src="images/yourpic.jpg">
</div>
```

What you do next is to put the border on the div. The next thing you have to do is to make the div `100px` wide.

Comment: @Abram I made a jsfiddle for you to illustrate how it looks: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/qvTkj/) . Looking at your code it looked like you wanted the height to be fixed at 65px.

Answer (score 0):

Hi now define this css

`img{vertical-align:top;}`

***[Live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/Ef7jA3em)***